# How template deduce const pointer type?

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I've tried following codes in [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void printType(T x) {
    std::cout << typeid(x).name() << std::endl;
}

void test() {
  const std::vector<int>::pointer a = new int[2];
  const int* c = new int[2];
  
  printType(a);//line15
  printType(c);//line16
  
  //delete
}

int main() {
  test();
}
```

The output is like:

```cpp
/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:15 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
void printType<int *>(int * x)
{
  std::operator<<(std::cout, typeid(x).name()).operator<<(std::endl);
}
#endif


/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:16 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
void printType<const int *>(const int * x)
{
  std::operator<<(std::cout, typeid(x).name()).operator<<(std::endl);
}
#endif
```

Since `std::vector<int>::pointer` = `int*`, why `const std::vector<int>::pointer a` has been interpreted as `int*` instead of `const int*`?

BTW: If the `pointer` is replaced by `value_type`, they will be both deduced as `int` instead of `const int`.

How compiler deal with `const` in this type of cases?

Comment: First, the `const` applies to the pointer not the `int`. Then, top level `const` are discarded for function parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since `std::vector<int>::pointer = int*`, why `const std::vector<int>::pointer` a has been interpreted as `int*` instead of
> `const int*`?

Because `const std::vector<int>::pointer` will be interpreted as `int* const` instead of `const int*`. Adding a `const`-qualifier to a pointer makes itself unmodifiable, not the value it points to.

If you need `const int*` then you should use `std::vector<int>::const_pointer` instead of `const std::vector<int>::pointer`.

Answer (score 3):

> why const `std::vector<int>::pointer a` has been interpreted as int* instead of const int*?

Because `std::vector<int>::pointer` is `int*`. A const qualified `int*` is `int* const`. It is not `const int*` aka `int const *` which is a distinct type. But the constness of the argument has no effect on deduction of the template, so it won't be deduced as `int* const`.

Comment: The compiler does not translate `const vector<int>::pointer` literally as `const int*`, but translate it by meaning as `const (int*) = a const pointer of int`. Can I interpret like this?

Comment: @user3059627 You cannot have parentheses in type names. But yes, `int * const` is a const pointer to (non-const) int.